# ajaxToolkit AutoCompleteExtender Chrome error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Facts:

ajaxToolkit AutoCompleteExtender in this specific screen works fine in IE, and Firefox

ajaxToolkit AutoCompleteExtender works fine in Chrome, in a different screen, same application

But not here. Right now I am getting errors like this:

> Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type
>   AjaxControlToolkit.Animation.Animation has already been registered.

and

> Uncaught Error: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script
>   'http://abc/def/ScriptResource.axd?d=uZ7YXSkj4n5b51-4hy2B1kBoyWBzAKQobQalIia8aju5_q790-3ZI8fdE9mfezSEesp77ToyxGv7_erOfA-X853srHT0dJkwMzZ98t3kSUkbkMEhd1StAYZDits_77x15a31Dr-0FO4ytW-aNwix2qkS_181&t=634263938860000000'
>   failed to load. Check for:  Inaccessible path.  Script errors. (IE)
>   Enable 'Display a notification about every script error' under
>   advanced settings.  Missing call to
>   Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded().

Anyone ever had any issues like this?

Scriptresource.axd is not something I tried to change before, so I am feeling totally lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging, I removed the UpdatePanel from the screen, and it is working fine in Chrom, Firefox, and IE as well.